# Null values using Extract values to table with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a shapefile with rectangular cells that i created with the function "create fishnet" and clipped it with a contour layer.

what i want to do is to add field to the attribute table that takes average values  from a raster based on the cells of my shapefiles.

I created a table with the function "extract values to table" and join it to the attribute table of my shapefile.

the problem is that i have some null values in some cells.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on the type of raster data you are using?  A screenshot would help illustrate the issue.

Comment: the raster data is the result of the simple kriging interpolation from a set of 226 point, and when i check the raster i don't have null value.

Comment: Is your shapefile extending beyond the extent of the raster data?

Comment: No, it's inside the raster

Comment: Have you tried calculating zonal statistics as table?:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000

Comment: i tried this function, it worked, but i still have the same problem with some records, but i figure out the problem, the records with null data are with null area too, because i maintain the default raster cell size (36) , which means cells under 1296 m² will be null. Can i change the cell size to 10 for example with no problem ?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can specify how the tool handles NoData in the "ignore_nodata" parameter.  Sorry, I cannot really speculate on your exact issue because I do not have all the facts.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i solve the problem, i generated the raster with "1" in cell size, so that arcgis can calculate the raster value that belongs to the same zone in my shapefile, i forgot to mentien that my shapefile contains features as rectangular cells as well as other forms in the contours du the feature clip form

Comment: Please consider including your solution as an answer so that this question can be considered resolved.

Comment: where can i do this?

Comment: Underneath the comments there should be a "answer your question" button.

Answer (score 1):

i generated the raster with "1" in cell size, so that when i execute "zonal statistics as table", arcgis can calculate the raster value that belongs to the same zone in my shapefile even the smallest polygon (with less than 1296 m² which correspond to 36 in default cell size)